# Elliptic polar coordinate

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates, elliptic-equations

Does anybody know why the elliptic polar coordinate of the ellipse is :
$$ \begin{cases} 
      x=a \ r\cos\theta \\
      \\
      y=b \ r\sin\theta
   \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Beware: this is NOT the polar equation of an ellipse, because $\theta$ is not the polar angle. Moreover, $r$ should be set to $1$. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center) for the correct equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general equation of an ellipse centerd at the origin and focus on the same Axis is $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1.$$
If you make the substitutio $X=x/a$, $Y=y/b$, you'll get $$X^2+Y^2=1$$ that is, the unit circumpherence. Using standard polar coordinates here, $$X=r\cos\theta,\ Y=r\sin\theta.$$ Finally, undo the substitution and you'll get your Elliptic Polar Coordinates.